# Access attribute from outside of a controller

Tags: api, asp.net-core, .net-core, formatting, asp.net-core-webapi

Is it possible to access a custom attribute of a controller action from outside of that controller? I have a custom output formatter that should return a file with a specific name. I made a custom attribute that accepts a string (filename) and I'd like to try to access the value of that attribute from within the custom output formatter.

```cs
public class FileAttribute : Attribute
{
public ExcelTemplateAttribute(string fileName)
{
    FileName = fileName;
}

    public string FileName { get; }
}
```

My `OutputFormatter` looks like this:

```cs
public class FileOutputFormatter : OutputFormatter
{
    public override Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context) 
    {
        // string filename = ???
    }
}
```

My API action returns a service

```cs
[File("Template.txt")]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery]int Id)
{
    IEnumerable<int> data = _kenoReport.GetReportData(Id);

    return Ok(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller and/or action information is not easily accessible outside of the MVC-specific parts of the middleware pipeline without resorting to complex (and easy-to-break) code relying on reflection.

However, one workaround is to use an action filter to add the attribute details to the `HttpContext.Items` dictionary (which is accessible throughout the entire middleware pipeline) and have the output formatter retrieve it later on in the middleware pipeline.

For example, you could make your `FileAttribute` derive from `ActionFilterAttribute` and have it add itself to `HttpContext.Items` (using a unique object reference as the key) when executing:

```csharp
public sealed class FileAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public FileAttribute(string filename)
    {
        Filename = filename;
    }

    public static object HttpContextItemKey { get; } = new object();

    public string Filename { get; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Items[HttpContextItemKey] = this;
    }
}
```

Then in your output formatter you can retrieve the attribute instance and access the filename:

```csharp
public sealed class FileOutputFormatter : OutputFormatter
{
    public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue(FileAttribute.HttpContextItemKey, out var item)
            && item is FileAttribute attribute)
        {
            var filename = attribute.Filename;

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```